# cannot find /lib64/libc.so.6

Tags: c, linux, arm, arm64

When i am doing the cross compilation for application, getting the following error.

```
opt/poky-h3-wayland/2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/5.1.1/real-ld: **cannot find /lib64/libc.so.6**
/opt/poky-h3-wayland/2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/5.1.1/real-ld: **cannot find /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a**
/opt/poky-h3-wayland/2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/5.1.1/real-ld: **cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Command used for compilation:**

```
aarch64-poky-linux-gcc pcm.c -I../r2/salvator-distribution/build/tmp/sysroots/salvator/usr/include/alsa/ -L../r2/salvator-distribution/build/tmp/sysroots/salvator/lib64/ -L../r2/salvator-distribution/build/tmp/sysroots/salvator/usr/lib64/ --sysroot=/opt/poky-monarch-h3-wayland/2.0.1/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux -o pcm
```

Please suggest where am doing mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Howcome you seem to be referencing two different sysroots there? That looks a bit off.

Comment: even with modified make command i am getting same error.

aarch64-poky-linux-gcc "--sysroot=/opt/poky-monarch-h3-wayland/2.0.1/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux" -I/home/rajesh/monarch/r2/monarch-distribution/build/tmp/sysroots/monarch/usr/include/alsa -o pcm pcm.o -L/home/rajesh/monarch/r2/monarch-distribution/build/tmp/sysroots/monarch/usr/lib64